# Database creation error: Access denied - Odoo 10

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, odoo, odoo-10, postgresql-10

I am new to odoo. I have an error regarding database creation in Odoo 10. I have tried all solutions given in internet like( Websites, Odoo Forums).

I am writing same admin_password in master password but when i opened odoo-server.conf then db_user and db_password is changed automatically to below code. Iam now running the server by giving db_user and db_password to configurations of LiClipse(Compiler). It runs but can't create new database. I have also tried that to make new user and start this server but all in vain.

`Odoo-server.conf` code:

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = rude
db_password = postgres
#addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons
[options]
#logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
addons_path=/home/rudehunk/odoo/projects/la10e/enterprise/addons,/home/rudehunk/odoo/projects/la10e/addons,/home/rudehunk/odoo/projects/la10e/my_addons
xmlrpc_port = 8015
```

I have also uncommented admin password and tried but didn't work. also tried all solutions given in internet, changed user and postgresql users accesses but also didn't worked. I have also changed postgres user access also didn't work. 
I have checked from all solutions which are given in internet in stackoverflow and odoo forums.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened to me. Changing the `xmlrpc_port` to the default [`8069`] worked for me.